# Django - Check if a non-foreign-key integer field exists as a Primary Key to another Model?

Tags: python, django

Say you have the following **legacy** model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    # more fields
```

`bar_id` is supposed to refer to a primary key from the `Bar` model, but for some reason, it's not registered as a foreign key. Now, how can I filter out all the `Foo`s that do not have corresponding `Bar` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make a list of primary keys of `Bar`s, and then filter out all `Foo`s that refer to such primary key.

```
Foo.objects.exclude(bar_id__in=Bar.objects.all().values_list('pk', flat=True))
```

This is a `QuerySet` that will give all `Foo` objects with an "*invalid*" `bar_id` (so an `id` that refers to a non-exiting `Bar`).

But it is better to use `ForeignKey` since then most databases will *enforce* this constraint in a transparant way. As a result, the database typically ensures that no such rows can exist at all. Typically you also add *triggers* to it what to do in case the `Bar` object that is referenced is for example removed.

Comment: This looks great. I will try it. Actually, this is a legacy project with existing database data (and some `Bar`s deleted), so changing the field to a foreign key may not be the best idea. Thanks, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Reading some of the comments makes me understand that OP would prefer to implement a foreign key but can not do so because of corrupt / missing data into database.

Two solutions:

1. Mark the column as foreign key in your Model, but do not enforce it
   in the database (use `--fake` flag while migrating using `manage.py`
   file. This approach helps in actually better defining your business
   / Model logic and enforces data Integrity in local development and
   environments.
2. Mark the column as foreign key in your Model and use
   `db_constraint=False` flag. Read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.db_constraint). Use this approach
   for legacy systems where data integrity has already been compromised
   and you just need to use Django's ORM joins the natural way.

Comment: Actually, after further investigations, I found out that the reason they didn't make it a foreign key was that the field was supposed to be a generic id field. That is, it can refer to the foreign key of another model (aside from Bar). But thanks for this answer.